# How to login and signup for 2 users separately in the firebase database? By using spinner to choose the usertype

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Im a beginner in Android Studio. I have an error on how to save the data of parents and tuition provider separately in the firebase database. I already make a research but all the tutorial seems differ from my style. Because, I have 2 activity which are signup.java and login.java.

**Flow of signup:-**
1. User need to fill up all the requirement needed such as firstname, lastname, usertype (parents or tuition provider), email and password. Fyi, to choose the usertype is by using a spinner.
2. Then, user need to verified their email first before they can login to their account.

**Flow of login:-**
1. If user already verified their email then they can login either as a parent or a tuition provider and go to their respective homepages.

I got 2 java class which are for Parents and Tuition Provider, and both class have same data:-

```
public class TuitionProvider
{
    String uid;
    String usertype;
    String firstname;
    String lastname;
    String email;

public TuitionProvider()
{

}

public TuitionProvider(String uid, String usertype, String firstname, String lastname, String email) {
    this.uid = uid;
    this.usertype = usertype;
    this.firstname = firstname;
    this.lastname = lastname;
    this.email = email;
}

public String getUid() {
    return uid;
}

public String getUsertype() {
    return usertype;
}

public String getFirstname() {
    return firstname;
}

public String getLastname() {
    return lastname;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}
```

}

Coding in signup.java:-

```
private void createUser()
{
    String uid = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    String usertype = RegisterUserType.getSelectedItem().toString();
    String firstname = RegisterFirstName.getText().toString().trim();
    String lastname = RegisterLastName.getText().toString().trim();
    String email = RegisterEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    if(mParentsRef.child("Parents").child(uid))
    {
        Parents parents = new Parents(uid, usertype, firstname, lastname, email);
        mParentsRef.child("Parents").child(uid).setValue(parents).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Data has been added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    else
    {
        TuitionProvider tuitionProvider = new TuitionProvider(uid, usertype, firstname, lastname, email);
        mTuitionProviderRef.child("Tuition Provider").child(uid).setValue(tuitionProvider).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task)
            {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    //Toast.makeText(Signup.this, "Data has been added successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(Signup.this, task.getException().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

For login.java, I cannot figure out how.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the question is not much clear.
Anyways, you are creating two separate directories for Parent and Provider, so you can login with email and password, validate it and then point to the specific directory using the Uid.

Comment: Can I have you email sir? So that I can share a video about my apps and the coding. Here, I can't copy all the coding here